# How to disable SOAP fault details in response? Springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot

I have a controller method with @PayloadRoot to an xml path.. If I post an xml payload that fails validation using Jaxb I get a SOAP response with a SOAP fault. This SOAP fault shows exception details. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to create a new EndpointInterceptor. Register this EndpointInterceptor in your WebServiceConfig. Override the handleFault() method and remove the SOAP Fault from the response method. Example:

WebServiceConfig.java

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(new MyEndpointInterceptor());
    }

    ...
}
```

MyEndpointInterceptor.java

```
public class MyEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        // handle the request message before the controller is invoked
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        // handle the response message after the controller is invoked
        return true;
    }

    @Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        try {
            // you can get your request and response messages
            SaajSoapMessage requestMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)messageContext.getRequest();
            SaajSoapMessage responseMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)messageContext.getResponse();

        // Test if you have a SOAP Fault
        if (responseMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault() != null) {
            // Do what you want with the SOAP Fault
            responseMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault().detachNode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // handle anything after the request, response, or fault are handled
    }
}
```